# Javascript syntax identification

Tags: javascript

Writing a regular expression, I found this code:

```
JSON.stringify(e.model.ProcedureDate).replace(/\"/g, '');
```

Why does `/\"/g` work without being quoted?  It isn't a string, and from what I gather, javascript doesn't have literals...  What would you call the text passed to `.replace()`?

Comment: FTR, `/\"/g` is the same as `/"/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), equivalent to:

```
new RegExp('\\"', 'g')
```

in the same way as `[]` is equivalent to `new Array(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

[Javascript has regular expression literals.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) That's an example of one.